# Azure sql server as backendpool to app gateway

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I’m trying to connect azure sql server as backendpool in app gateway waf v2 and added respective listener, rules and http settings to point to sql server. But the backend health is failing with error to open nsg for the port 65200 to 65535. Since the sql server don’t have any network, how will I enable the ports to communicate with app gateway. Can you please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as Application Gateway works at layer 7 responding to HTTP/HTTPS requests. In this scenario your best bet is implementing Azure loadbalacner as Load Balancer load-balances traffic at layer 4 (TCP or UDP).